# Error in perl producer to connect to activemq server

Tags: perl, activemq-classic, eof, stomp, producer

I am trying out the perl producer to talk to ActiveMq. Please find the code which i have tried out. It is giving me an error  **"*** Net::STOMP::Client::IO::receive_data(): cannot sysread(): EOF"**

After debugging the error is at `$stomp->connect();`
Kindly let me know why this error at this point... I'm not able to find much help about this online..

Thanks in advance

I've tried to telnet to the url which I'm trying to get connected. First it is getting connected and at the end it is some error message as below:

```
CacheEnabledSizePrefixDisabled MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay'TcpNoDelayEnabledMaxInactivityDurationu0TightEncodingEnabledStackTraceEnabledPuTTY
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Which means that the connection is getting closed.

**These are the broker logs where I'm suspecting some error:**

```
2012-12-07 14:44:12,021 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:57404 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:57404@61616
2012-12-07 14:44:12,021 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:57403 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:57403@61616
2012-12-07 14:44:12,024 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:57405 failed: java.io.IOException: Unknown data type: 47 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:57405@61616
2012-12-07 14:44:12,024 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:57405 failed: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://127.0.0.1:57405 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | Async Exception Handler
2012-12-07 16:08:55,045 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:58008 failed: java.io.IOException: Unknown data type: 69 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:58008@61616
2012-12-07 16:08:55,045 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:58008 failed: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://127.0.0.1:58008 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | Async Exception Handler
```

**Code:**

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::STOMP::Client;
my $stomp = Net::STOMP::Client->new(uri => "tcp://$url:$port");
my $peer = $stomp->peer();
  printf("connected to broker %s (IP %s), port %d\n",
      $peer->host(), $peer->addr(), $peer->port());
  $stomp->connect();
  printf("speaking STOMP %s with server %s\n",
      $stomp->version(), $stomp->server() || "UNKNOWN");
  printf("session %s started\n", $stomp->session());
  $stomp->disconnect();
  printf("session ended\n");
```

Comment: which line in the posted sample code gives the error, hard to guess at what's going wrong without more info.  Broker logs are also a good place to look.

Comment: what's the broker config look like?

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped if you had told us which line the error occurred on, since that would point out which call was failing with that error.

There have been some terribly buggy versions of Perl's STOMP libraries. Make sure you're using the latest version from CPAN and not an old version that came preinstalled on your system.